# live-update results generated from AI

Tags: plotly-dash

Below is the dash interface to show the chat between human and AI, and I would like to use live stream to update AI answers.

I set the dcc interval in the layout section, and the question AI is initiated by function “def run_chatbot(n_clicks, n_submit, user_input, chat_history):”

Log stores answer generated from machine, and I would like if log got new content and should be updated to the chatdisplay, and if no update from log, then the livestream should not work

I am confusing about callback function for dcc.interval, tried a couple times cannot make it work, so any advice would be great.

```
import os
import time
from textwrap import dedent
import dash
from dash import html
from dash import dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from PIL import Image
import openai


def Header(name, app):
    app.title = 'ChatHub'
    title = html.H1(name, style={"margin-top": 5})
    logo = html.Img(
        src=app.get_asset_url("logo.png"), style={"float": "right", "height": 60}
    )
    return dbc.Row([dbc.Col(title, md=8), dbc.Col(logo, md=4)])


def intersperse(lst, item):
    result = [item] * (len(lst) * 2 - 1)
    result[0::2] = lst
    return result

# Define app
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
server = app.server


# Define Layout
conversation = html.Div(
    html.Div(id="display-conversation"),

)

controls = dbc.InputGroup(
    [
        dbc.Input(id="user-input", placeholder="Write to the chatbot...", type="text"),
        dbc.Button("Submit", id="submit", n_clicks=0), 
    ]
)

app.layout = dbc.Container(
    fluid=False,
    children=[
        Header("ChatBot", app),
        html.Hr(),
        dcc.Store(id="store-conversation", data=""),
        conversation,
        controls,

        dcc.Interval(
            id='interval-component',
            interval=1*1000,  # in milliseconds
            n_intervals=0 )
    ],
)



@app.callback(
    Output("display-conversation", "children"), [Input("store-conversation", "data")]
)
def update_display(chat_history):
    return [
        textbox(x, box="user") if i % 2 == 0 else textbox(x, box="AI")
        for i, x in enumerate(chat_history.split("<split>")[:-1])
    ]

@app.callback(
    Output("user-input", "value"),
    [Input("submit", "n_clicks"), Input("user-input", "n_submit")],
)
def clear_input(n_clicks, n_submit):
    return ""

@app.callback(
    [Output("store-conversation", "data"), Output("loading-component", "children")],
    [Input("submit", "n_clicks"), Input("user-input", "n_submit")],
    [State("user-input", "value"), State("store-conversation", "data")],
)
def run_chatbot(n_clicks, n_submit, user_input, chat_history):
    if n_clicks == 0 and n_submit is None:
        return "", None

    if user_input is None or user_input == "":
        return chat_history, None

    name = 'AI'

    # First add the user input to the chat history
    chat_history += f"You: {user_input}<split>"

    model_input = prompt + chat_history.replace("<split>", "\n")
    print(model_input)
    output_stream = run_query(graph, model_input)
    log=[]
    model_output = '\n'.join(list1)
    #model_output = conversation_chain.predict(input=user_input)
    #model_output = conversation.choices[0].text.strip()

    chat_history += f"{model_output}<split>"

    return chat_history, None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1', port=8000)
```